# Get all data from inner tags using loop in php

Tags: php

I need help to get data using only php domxparser query, I need to loop through p element inside 'data' class and get inside elements data. using domxquery.

```
<div class="data">
<p>
    <em>field 1 </em>
    <span> value 1</span>
</p>
<p>
    <em>field 2 </em>
    <span> value 2</span>
</p>
<p>
    <em>field 3 </em>
    <span> value 3</span>
</p>
<p>
    <em>field 4 </em>
    <span> value </span>
</p>
```

//i have done this but not working

```
$contract = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'data')]");

$contract_p="";

foreach ($contract as $pcon) 
{
   $contract_p = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@name), ' '), 'p')]",$contract);
}           

foreach ($contract_p as $con) 
{
    $name = $xpath->query('div[@name="span"]', $con);               

    foreach ($name as $value)
    {
        var_dump($value->nodeValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3649115 what result are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath ($dom);

$array = array();

$lisings = $xpath->query ("//div[@class='data']//p");

foreach ($lisings as $lising) {

    $tmp_array = array();

    $em_tags = $xpath->query (".//em", $lising);
    foreach($em_tags as $em_tag) {
        $tmp_array['em'] = $em_tag->nodeValue;
    }

    $em_spans = $xpath->query (".//span", $lising);
    foreach($em_spans as $em_span) {
        $tmp_array['span'] = $em_span->nodeValue;
    }

    $array[] = $tmp_array;  
}

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/768109)

```
<?php

$object = new DOMDocument();
$object->loadHTML('<div class="data">
<p>
    <em>field 1 </em>
    <span> value 1</span>
</p>
<p>
    <em>field 2 </em>
    <span> value 2</span>
</p>
<p>
    <em>field 3 </em>
    <span> value 3</span>
</p>
<p>
    <em>field 4 </em>
    <span> value </span>
</p></div>');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($object);
$elements = $xpath->query('//*[@class="data"]');
$ems=array();
$spans=array();
foreach($elements as $node)
{
    foreach($node->childNodes as $element)
    {
        if(isset($element->tagName) && $element->tagName=="p")
        {
            foreach($element->childNodes as $requireNode)
            {
                if(isset($requireNode->tagName) && $requireNode->tagName=="em")
                {
                    $ems[]=$requireNode->textContent;
                }
                elseif(isset($requireNode->tagName) && $requireNode->tagName=="span")
                {
                    $spans[]=$requireNode->textContent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$result=array_combine($ems, $spans);
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [field 1 ] =>  value 1
    [field 2 ] =>  value 2
    [field 3 ] =>  value 3
    [field 4 ] =>  value 
)
```